# How to make an exact replica of a branch?

Tags: clearcase

I'm having a ClearCase read-only branch `A`.

I want to create an exact copy/replica of Branch `A` and create another Branch `B`.
Can we make such an exact replica of branch `A` at byte level?
Is this possible?

**Update:**
As suggested by @VonC, I tried to make a change in the Branch A, let's call it "A_read" and it gave me an error in the checkout. Sorry had to paint some info as per company policy.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply create a `viewB` which starts at a label `A` you have set in `viewA`.
Or you start from `A/LATEST`:

That `viewB` will have a selection rule like:

```
element .../A/LATEST -mkbranch B
# or
element * A -mkbranch B
element * /main/LATEST
```

That means:

- it select the latest version in branch `A` (`.../A` because `A` can derive from `/main` or `/main/someOtherBranch`, or `/main/X/Y/...`)
- it will create branch `B` only if there is a checkout.

A branch in ClearCase has a starting point, and will have version of its own only once changes are versioned (checkout/checkin).

Right now, with that selection rule, branch `B` is identical to `A`, in that it starts from the versions selected by `A`.

Comment: What you have suggested isn't a replica. You have designed the config spec so that the versions of elements are selected according to what we want, which is a good approach but it's kinda a workaround. I'm looking for an exact byte level replica/exact copy of the branch A so that config spec of branch B doesn't contain any reference to branch A. How to do that in clearcase?

Comment: @SaurabhPatil It *is* a replica, because of the nature of branches in ClearCase. Before suggesting something else (which would actually be a wrokaround), I need to understand *why* you need what you call a "replica". Can you tell me more about its intended usage?

Comment: Sure. The thing is we have a branch A which is read only. I want to do code changes on it's code and push it to production. As I can't write to that branch A I need it's clone branch B with exact same code where I can read/write. Then I would take a build on Branch B and deploy that build to production.

Comment: @SaurabhPatil How a branch would be "read-only"? What I suggest allows you to create your own branch starting from branch A content. But first, what kind of error do you see when trying to write to branch A?

Comment: It's a long story.. it's an auto created branch. I will try to check in some code to branch A and would report the error I get. Thank you for your prompt replies.

Comment: @SaurabhPatil No problem. Again, even if you had some kind of permission denied, you should be able to set a label of your own to mark what branch A currently references, and make your own changes with from branch B (which would start from branch A)

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. Please check. Can ccadmin give me the write access? Is it possible?

Comment: @SaurabhPatil Instead of trying to checkout from the (locked) branch A, try and set a label first (as I suggest in the answer), and to a checkout from that label (which is the first line of the config spec I mention  in the answer)